# Cant make auth through php artisan make:auth or php artisan ui vue --auth, Laravel 7.9.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

when ever i try to install ui through composer require laravel/ui it fails

```
$ composer require laravel/ui

Using version ^2.0 for laravel/ui

./composer.json has been updated

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Nothing to install or update

Generating optimized autoload files


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "app/database/migrations" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Answer (score 0):

In composer.json you can try to remove from `classpath` the `app/database/migration`